# How to chain eloquent relation in route in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am creating an application in Laravel which has 3 models with relationships to each other.

I have got a problem in routing where I show particular category according to the id. I do like this:

```
Route::apiResource('/categories', 'Core\CategoryController');

Route::prefix('categories')->group(function() {
    Route::apiResource('/{category}/sub_categories', 'Core\SubCategoryController');

    Route::prefix('sub_categories')->group(function() {
        Route::apiResource('/{sub_category}/sub_sub_categories', 'Core\SubSubCategoryController');
    });
});
```

I am able to do `http://localhost:8080/api/categories/3/sub_categories`. However, I am not able to do `http://localhost:8080/api/categories/3/sub_categories/1/sub_sub_categories`. I am not able to get the id of category and display it in url. What I am able to do is this -> `http://localhost:8080/api/categories/sub_categories/1/sub_sub_categories`

So, how can I display the id of category in that URL?

I tried:

```
Route::prefix('/{category}/sub_categories')->group(function() {
    Route::apiResource('/{sub_category}/sub_sub_categories', 'Core\SubSubCategoryController');
});
```

However, that didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
Route::prefix('categories')->group(function() {
    Route::apiResource('/{category}/sub_categories/{sub_category}/sub_sub_categories', 'Core\SubSubCategoryController');
    Route::apiResource('/{category}/sub_categories', 'Core\SubCategoryController');
});
```

Comment: How do I pass the category id from sub sub category?